# Wildcard on DocumentRoot for virtualhost

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I use this snippet for wildcard subdomain and works good:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/subdomains
  ServerName subdomains.example.com
  ServerAlias *.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

now i want to use wildcard in DocumentRoot too, for example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/*
  ServerName sumdomains.example.com
  ServerAlias *.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

that means if call 'username.example.com', DocumentRoot points to '/var/www/username/'.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that directly but you can rewrite your urls to have the same behavior

Add these 2 lines in your config file

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(.*) /%{HTTP_HOST}/$1
```

a request to http://user.example.com/foo.html will fetch the file **/var/www/user.example.com/foo.html**

Comment: thanks a lot. but could you give me a RewriteRule that request to http://user.example.com/foo.html fetch file from /var/www/user/foo.html ?